# Swift properties - avoid multiple declarations over n class?

Tags: xcode, swift, properties, protocols

I've defined in Swift the following protocol:

```
protocol Condition {

var column : RepositoryTableColumn! {get set}
var sourceTable : RepositoryTable! {get set}
var conditionalValue : String! {get set}
var preventsClear : Bool! {get set}

func getCondition() -> String
func accept(visitor : ConditionVisitor)
```

}

And the protocol is extended by (for now on) 8 classes meaning that each class needs to have a declaration as:

```
class IsEqual : Condition {

var column : RepositoryTableColumn!
var sourceTable : RepositoryTable!
var conditionalValue : String!
var preventsClear : Bool!

}
```

My question is, how is it possible to avoid having these four declarations within every class? The reason why I'm trying to avoid this is that I don't want to duplicate code, i.e. in this case declarations.

For the constructor I've created an extension of the Condition class, however this cannot imply to properties because extensions cannot hold them.

Any piece of advice?

Answer (score 0):

If your properties can be computed instead of stored you could create an `extension` of `Condition` that provides default implementations for anything that adopts your protocol. Unfortunately you can't add stored properties to classes in extensions, so you may have to rearchitect your model if brevity is that important to you.